# バックトラッキング法を用いた分割数の出力について

Tags: java

5は、{5}{1,4}{1,1,3}{1,1,1,2}{1,1,1,1,1}{2,3}{2,1,2}これらの正の整数の和で表されます。
また、7は、{7}{1,6}{1,1,5}{1,1,1,4}{1,1,1,1,3}{1,1,1,1,1,2}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{2,5}{2,1,4}{2,1,1,3}{2,1,1,1,2}{3,4}{3,1,3}{1,2,2,2}{2,2,3}のように表されますが、私の書いたプログラムでは、{1,2,2,2}{2,2,3}が出力されません。つまり、3つ以上の和の組み合わせのときに1以外のものを出力する方法が分かりません。1~5では、間の数字が1でもすべてのパターンを書くことができたのですが…

プログラム全体を修正する必要があると思いますが具体的にどう修正すればよいか教えていただきたいです。
n,iは変化していき、rは固定(上では、5,7）のつもりで書きました。

**ソースコード:**

```java
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        function(1, 4, 4);
    }
    
    public static void function(int i, int n, int r) {
        if (i >= n) return;
    
        write(i, n, r);
    
        if (n-1 <= i) {
            function(i+1, r-i, r);
        }
        
        function(i,n-1,r);
        
    }
    
    public static void write(int i, int n, int r){
        int k = r-(n-1)-i;
        if (r == n) System.out.print("{"+n+"}");
        System.out.print("{"+i);

        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            System.out.print(",1");
        }
        System.out.print(","+(n-1)+"}");
   }
}
```

**実行結果:**

```
function(1,4,4):
ACTUAL:   {4}{1,3}{1,1,2}{1,1,1,1}{2,2}
EXPECTED: {4}{1,3}{1,1,2}{1,1,1,1}{2,2}
function(1,5,5):
ACTUAL:   {5}{1,4}{1,1,3}{1,1,1,2}{1,1,1,1,1}{2,3}{2,1,2}
EXPECTED: {5}{1,4}{1,1,3}{1,1,1,2}{1,1,1,1,1}{2,3}{2,1,2}
function(1,7,7):
ACTUAL:   {7}{1,6}{1,1,5}{1,1,1,4}{1,1,1,1,3}{1,1,1,1,1,2}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{2,5}{2,1,4}{2,1,1,3}{2,1,1,1,2}{3,4}{3,1,3}
EXPECTED: {7}{1,6}{1,1,5}{1,1,1,4}{1,1,1,1,3}{1,1,1,1,1,2}{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{2,5}{2,1,4}{2,1,1,3}{2,1,1,1,2}{3,4}{3,1,3}{1,2,2,2}{2,2,3}
```

Comment: 3つの引数はそれぞれどういう意味をもたせることを想定したものですか？(なぜ初期値が`(1,4,4)`なのでしょうか？なぜ[`int`型](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/80522/%e3%83%90%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%83%88%e3%83%a9%e3%83%83%e3%82%ad%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0%e6%b3%95%e3%82%92%e7%94%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e5%88%86%e5%89%b2%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ae%e5%87%ba%e5%8a%9b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment90984_80527)なのでしょうか？)

Comment: @DEWAKazuyuki-出羽和之  ご回答ありがとうございます。rを現したい数字(固定)とし、i、とnに分解してそして合計がnになるものの組み合わせとiの和でrを表すことを想定していました。

Comment: その説明だと、 `i + n = r` (例えば `(1, 3, 4)`) になるべきのように思うのですが、どうでしょうか、私が理解を誤っているでしょうか。